# React Hooks: Why isn't setState causing Context.provider to rerender?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, setstate, use-ref

### CONTEXT

I have the following React functional component:

```
export const LocationProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
    const [visLocationData, setVisLocationData] = React.useState<VisLocationData>({});

    const addLocationData = React.useCallback((id: string, rect: ClientRect) => {
        setVisLocationData((prevData) => {
            console.log(`[Debugging]: Setting location data for ${id}`); // Debugging
            prevData[id] = rect;
            return prevData;
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(`[Debugging]: Rendering location provider`); // Debugging

    return (
        <VisLocationContext.Provider value={{visLocationData, addLocationData}}>
            {children}
        </VisLocationContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I have ~17 child components calling `addLocationData`, but the children never see the updated `visLocationData` state.

Additionally, the print statements I see are `[Debugging]: Rendering location provider` followed by 17 instances of `[Debugging]: Setting location data for ${id}`.

Inspecting the Components in the React developer tools, I do see the correct state for the `LocationProvider`, it just never makes its way down to the children in the provider.

### Questions

1. Why don't the child components ever see the updated `visLocationData` state?
2. Shouldn't I see pairs of the print statements I've got- each time the state is updated (`...setting location data...`)the function is re-called/re-rendered (`...Rendering location provider`)?

### Note

`addLocationData` is called as part of a ref:

```
export const Resource: React.FC<Resource<any>> = (props) => {
    const {addLocationData} = useVisLocation();
    const ref = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!ref || !ref.current || !addLocationData) {
            return;
        }
        addLocationData( props.id, (ref.current! as HTMLDivElement).getBoundingClientRect());
    }, [addLocationData]);

    return(<div className={"resource"} ref={ref}>{props.id}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The change

```
        setVisLocationData((prevData) => {
            console.log(`[Debugging]: Setting location data for ${id}`); // Debugging
            prevData[id] = rect;
            return prevData;
        });
    }, []);
```

should be

```
        setVisLocationData((prevData) => {
            console.log(`[Debugging]: Setting location data for ${id}`); // Debugging
            return {...prevData, [id]: rect};
        });
    }, []);
```

### The reason

My original approach mutates the existing state object and then returns the mutated state.  The corrected approach returns a completely new object.

Details: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.